# Inserting multiple rows from a form to MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an invoice system. I came to a point where I need your help.

i need to store multiple rows in a form to MySql at once.

For example this is my code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO invoice (client_name, client_address, client_phone, client_number, invoice_date, invoice_number, item_number, item_name, item_desc, item_quantity, item_unit, item_total, total, net_value)
VALUES
('$_POST[client_name]','$_POST[client_address]','$_POST[client_phone]','$_POST[client_number]','$_POST[invoice_date]','$_POST[invoice_number]','$_POST[item_number]','$_POST[item_name]','$_POST[item_desc]','$_POST[item_quantity]','$_POST[item_unit]','$_POST[item_total]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[net_value]')";
```

The form has many inputs obviously. However, there are 5 inputs which will have multiple values (item_number, item_name, item_desc, item_quantity and item_unit)

so how can i achieve to store this form all at one php $_POST

Comment: I think you are talking about invoice line and technically they should go to a different table by looping through the input data with idinvoice as reference to this table

Comment: Please be aware to escape `$_POST` data with `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent `SQL injection`

Comment: seems you will need two tables, one to store the invoice number etc, one to store item detail

Comment: no worries about SQL injection this program will be stored locally on my personal computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this all in one table then here is the alternate solution for you:

I hope you are getting $_POST['item_number'],$_POST['item_name'],$_POST['item_desc'],$_POST['item_quantity'],$_POST['item_unit'],$_POST['item_total'] as array in POST.

Change datatype of all these fields to TEXT first.
Then
while inserting in table `invoice` you can pass it as json_encode($_POST['item_number']) for all these fields.
and whenever you want it to display you will need to json_encode these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are really asking here. If for instance you have your post variable and that is an array of assocated array values such as

$_POST[0][client_name] and so on then you could do this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO invoice (client_name, client_address, client_phone, client_number, invoice_date, invoice_number, item_number, item_name, item_desc, item_quantity, item_unit, item_total, total, net_value)
VALUES";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){
if(($i+1) == sizeof($_POST)){
$sql .="('$_POST[$i][client_name]','$_POST[$i][client_address]','$_POST[$i][client_phone]','$_POST[$i][client_number]','$_POST[$i][invoice_date]','$_POST[$i][invoice_number]','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_quantity]','$_POST[$i][item_unit]','$_POST[$i][item_total]','$_POST[$i][total]','$_POST[$i][net_value]')";
}else{
$sql .="('$_POST[$i][client_name]','$_POST[$i][client_address]','$_POST[$i][client_phone]','$_POST[$i][client_number]','$_POST[$i][invoice_date]','$_POST[$i][invoice_number]','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_quantity]','$_POST[$i][item_unit]','$_POST[$i][item_total]','$_POST[$i][total]','$_POST[$i][net_value]'),";
}
}
```

Then you could execute the $sql variable all in one go. If this is not how you mean could you explain what data is in your $_POST variable other then what you have already explained.

Comment: The code i wrote above is meant to be for a very simple invoicing system. i need to store all values in one table only but i am facing a problem with the items inputs because the item inputs (item_number, item_name, item_desc , item_quantity, item_unit) might have multiple rows so i want to be able to get these values in addition to the client_name and other fields and store it at onece in the database. BTW I don't know if this can be achieved with a single table but i really want to only have one table.

Comment: If you want this all in one table then here is the alternate solution for you:


I hope you are getting $_POST['item_number'],$_POST['item_name'],$_POST['item_desc'],$_POST['item_quantity'],$_POST['item_unit'],$_POST['item_total'] as array in POST.

Change datatype of all these fields to TEXT first.
Then
while inserting in table `invoice` you can pass it as json_encode($_POST['item_number']) for all these fields.
and whenever you want it to display you will need to json_encode these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I see, this is better done by splitting the data or normalising it. You really need two tables one for the invoice and the other for the item lines.

table one
id (auto_increment)
client_name
client_address
client_phone
client_number
invoice_date
invoice_number
invoice_total in your example you have this as total
invoice_net_value in your example you have this as net_value

Table two

id (auto_increment) 
table_one_id 
item_number
item_name
item_desc
item_quantity
item_unit
item_total

your insert statements will be as follows this will be really simple you should be using some sort of db framework tho.

```
$sql = "insert into table_one (client_name,client_address,client_phone,client_number,invoice_date,invoice_number,invoice_total,invoice_net_value) values('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['client_name'])."'",'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['client_phone'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['client_number'])."','",mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['invoice_date'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['invoice_number'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['invoice_total'])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['invoice_net_value'])."')";
```

Execute the statment and then do the following:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Use the id and do another insert for the rest of the data.

```
$sql = "insert into table_two (table_one_id,item_number,item_name,item_desc,item_quantity,item_unit,item_total) values";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($_POST);$i++){
if(($i+1) == sizeof($_POST)){
$sql .="('$id','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_quantity]','$_POST[$i][item_unit]','$_POST[$i][item_total]')";
}else{
$sql .="('$id','$_POST[$i][item_number]','$_POST[$i][item_name]','$_POST[$i][item_desc]','$_POST[$i][item_quantity]','$_POST[$i][item_unit]','$_POST[$i][item_total]'),";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create tow tables for it:
Add one field `invoice_id` primary key to relate with invoice_item table
Table : invoice (invoice_id,client_name, client_address, client_phone, client_number, invoice_date, invoice_number)

Table : invoice_item (invoice_item_id,fk_invoice_id,item_number, item_name, item_desc, item_quantity, item_unit, item_total,net_value)

Now you need to do LOOP :

```
Here .... Fire query to insert into `invoice` table for the fields : invoice_id,client_name, client_address, client_phone, client_number, invoice_date, invoice_number
```

-> get last insert id of `invoice` table to be inserted into invoice_item table for the field `fk_invoice_id`

```
foreach ($_POST AS $k=>$v)
```

{
 // Fire query to insert into invoice_item table for fields : invoice_item_id,fk_invoice_id,item_number, item_name, item_desc, item_quantity, item_unit, item_total,net_value
}